# Replace first match beneath a pattern using sed

Tags: linux, sed, expression, gnu

I have a file with user accounts:

```
[account]
username                      = mike
password                      = mike
expdate                       = 2015-02-14
city                          = blah
address                       = blah

[account]
username                      = george
password                      = george
city                          = blah
address                       = blah
expdate                       = 2015-02-14

[account]
username                      = hans
password                      = hans
city                          = blah
expdate                       = 2015-02-14
address                       = blah
```

So each user account starts with [account] and has certain values beneath it.

I'd like to use GNU sed to alter the expdate value for user "mike" to:

```
expdate                       = 2016-02-14
```

So it should only alter it after the first occurrence of:

```
username                      = mike
```

The problem is, expdate can be any amount of lines beneath the username.

Can this be solved with GNU sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed '/mike/,/\[account\]/{s/\(expdate[^=]\+=\).*/\1 2016-02-14/}' yourfile
```

Comment: This may fail if there are tabs between `expdate` and `=`

Comment: Thanks. there are always spaces between "expdate" and "=", so I added a dot. I also added a $ to mark the end of the username: sed '/username$/,/\[account\]/{s/\(expdate.*=\).*/\1 2016-02-14/}'

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^username/{u=$3}
     {
       if(u=="mike" && ($1~/expdate/))
       $3="2016-02-14"
     }1' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks, however I do not have awk installed on this machine.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an `OScam` pay server ;)
Changing the config file manually of the OSCam server is not a good ting, its need a restart to read it.

This is version based on user1939168 version
Formatting is not changed, and it does not matter if its space or tab separated.

```
awk '/^username/{f=$3} f=="mike" && $1=="expdate" {sub(/2015/,"2016")}1'
[account]
username                      = mike
password                      = mike
expdate                       = 2016-02-14
city                          = blah
address                       = blah
```

This assume that `user` name comes before `expdate` and it `OSCam` it does, so should work fine.

Comment: I don't have awk installed on this machine.

Comment: What OS are you on?  As far as I have seen, all `dreambox` have it, same with `VU+` and other

Comment: I'm running a very minimal version of busybox on a alix pc-engine (amd geode lx800), And I've compiled GNU sed on top of it.

Comment: I would suggested you to use a some more powerful linux, like ubuntu.  The you can add `munin` to graph what is going on in your `OSCam` server.

Comment: It's a small server, and busybox was built with buildroot against uclibc. The Alix pc-engine is a small and low-power embedded platform which is not suitable for a full linux distro like ubuntu. Thanks I'll look up munin and see if I can compile it :)